# Modelling grooves on a cylinder

Tags: modeling

How can I model the grooves of a ventilation pipe?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is shown on the image is most likely work for normal or bump maps. Although those can be easily created from highpoly to lowpoly baking so modeling highpoly will be required (shown in the answer)

Answer (score 4):

You may do it fast using the ***Array Modifier*** and some basic modeling tools.
[image]

Add a *cylinder* with no fill, then subdivide it in the middle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Bevel the loopcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and set its thickness. Next inset the faces with <kbd>I</kbd> to create extra loopcuts for subsurf creasing. Then extrude the loop of faces (<kbd>E</kbd>) and scale it along Z and Y axis only (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>). Repeat it twice, then inset the faces again. Finally add a ***Subsurf Modifier*** and apply the smooth shading. One segment is ready.
[image]

Add the ***Array Modifier*** and set it above the ***Subsurf***. Set the *Count number* as you like and check the *Merge* checkbox.
[image]

To change the angle of the carvings select one in *Edit Mode* with <kbd>B</kbd>, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to shear it.
[image]

Finally you may apply the ***Array***, add the ***Solidify Modifier*** (to give the pipe a thickness) and add loopcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) at the edges of a pipe.
[image]